# Increase the margin of every second x-axis tick ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, margin

I'm looking for a way to move every second `x-axis` tick downwards and have the `tick` line go down with it.
I can change the general margin and tick length for all ticks with:

```
#MWE
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(cars, aes(dist, speed))+
   geom_point()+
   theme(
       axis.ticks.length.x = unit(15, "pt")
   )
```

But, I would like the x-axis ticks 0, 50, and 100 (i.e., every second tick) to be without the added top margin.
A generalized answer is preferred as my x-axis is categorical and not numerical (and contains 430 ticks, so nothing I can set by hand).

Any ideas?

#### Edit:

Output should be:
[image]

#### Edit2:

A more intricate example would be:

```
#MWE
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, price, fill = clarity, group = clarity))+
geom_col(position = 'dodge')+
theme(
    axis.ticks.length.x = unit(15, "pt")
)
```

Comment: hi you can use `theme()` to alter the layout of your plot. If you want to change the axis this is done by the `scale`functions. For your case `scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,50,100))`helps with the axis ticks. You should probably add a picture to explain which margin you want to increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit -- added categorical approach at bottom.

Here's a hack. Hope there's a better way!

```
ticks <- data.frame(
  x = 25*0:5,
  y = rep(c(-0.2, -2), 3)
)

ggplot(cars, aes(dist, speed))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_rect(fill = "white", xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf,
            ymin = 0, ymax = -5) +
  geom_segment(data = ticks,
               aes(x = x, xend = x,
                   y = 0, yend = y)) +
  geom_text(data = ticks,
            aes(x = x, y = y, label = x), vjust = 1.5) +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 25*0:5, labels = NULL, name = "") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

### [image]

Here's a similar approach used with a categorical x.

```
cats <- sort(as.character(unique(diamonds$cut)))
ticks <- data.frame(x = cats)
ticks$y = ifelse(seq_along(cats) %% 2, -500, -2000)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, price, fill = clarity, group = clarity))+
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  annotate("rect", fill = "white",
           xmin = 0.4, xmax = length(cats) + 0.6,
           ymin = 0, ymax = -3000) +
  geom_segment(data = ticks, inherit.aes = F,
               aes(x = x, xend = x,
                   y = 0, yend = y))  +
  geom_text(data = ticks, inherit.aes = F,
            aes(x = x, y = y, label = x), vjust = 1.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = NULL, name = "cut") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0, 0.05))) +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. I'll accept this for know as it does solve the question.
Couple of questions:
(1) Would you modify `y` in `ticks` to increase spacing?
(2) if `x` is categorical, (I can upload a MWE if needed) would you change `x` in `ticks` to the order of the categories?
Do I understand your solution correctly?

Comment: Please see my second example, I did not managed to get your hack to work on it. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you again. For some reason (on my data) the y-axis goes down with the labels. Do you know where this error stems from?

Comment: Not sure. I added the `expand_scale(mult = c(0, 0.05)))` part to specify that the y axis should go no lower than the data, which starts at 0.

Comment: Oh, ok, I have that in my code as well. I will have too double check then. I just removed the axis in all for now.